# Excel VBA - add cell value to array

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to add the value of a cell in an array, but i am getting a type mismatch error in my code. Why is this happening?

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim arr As Variant

Set rng = Range("panel_is_on")

For Each cell In rng
    If cell.Value2 = "On" Then
        If cell.Offset(0, -1).Value2 = "ISJ" Or cell.Offset(0, -1).Value2 = "BSJ" Then
            arr(i) = cell.Offset(0, -3).Value2
            i = i + 1
        End If
    End If
Next cell
```

Comment: Quick test for you:  `Debug.Print IsArray(arr)`

Comment: `arr` is not an array - `Dim arr() As Variant` then `redim preserve` in the loop to extend it as needed.

Comment: ok, this works, but all elements in the array are empty apart from the last one

Comment: Can you post your revised code?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
For Each cell In rng

If cell.Value2 = "On" Then
    If cell.Offset(0, -1).Value2 = "ISJ" Or cell.Offset(0, -1).Value2 = "BSJ" Then
    i = i + 1
    ReDim Preserve arr(1 To i)
    arr(i) = cell.Offset(0, -3).Value2
 End if 
Next cell
```